# Reference an object where the key has bracket

Tags: php, object

When I dump the result ($items) this is the "tags" object:

```
["tags"]=> object(stdClass)#20 (1) { 
    ["number::[Device]."]=> string(3) "381" 
}
```

I need that value "381" but how can I reference it?

this is the array i'm creating to send to the database:

```
  foreach ($items as $item) {
            $arg = array (
                @$item->id,
                **@$item->tags->{Number::[Device].}**,
                @$item->presentation->name,
                @$item->model,
                @$item->reportedTimeZone,
            );
```

I have tried a number of things but I either get an error or NULL.

Thanks.

Comment: Put it in quotes inside `->{}`.

Comment: Quote it `$item->tags->{'number::[Device].'}`

Comment: Or `(array)$item->tags['Number::[Device].']` might work.